# Why can't record the request which result in 404 error?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, http-status-code-404

```
curl -I -w %{http_code}  http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600024.html
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx

curl -I -w %{http_code}  http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
```

It shows that `http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600024.html` don't exist,its http error code is 404;`http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html` do exist,its http error code is 200.

I want to write a spider to record the request which result in 404 error.

1. Add `HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES` in `middlewares.py`.

   HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES = [404,403,406, 408, 500, 503, 504]
2. Add log setting in `settings.py`.

   LOG_LEVEL = "CRITICAL"
   LOG_FILE = "mylog"
3. Create a spider.

   ```
   import scrapy
   from info.items import InfoItem
   import logging

   class InfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
       handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
       name = 'info'
       allowed_domains = ['quotes.money.163.com']
       start_urls = [ r"http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html",
                  r"http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600024.html"]

       def parse(self, response):
           item = StockinfoItem()
           if(response.status == 200):logging.critical("url whose status is 200 : " + response.url)
           if(response.status == 404):logging.critical("url whose status is 404 : " + response.url)
   ```

Open mylog file after running the spider.

```
2019-04-25 08:47:57 [root] CRITICAL: url whose status is 200 : http://quotes.money.163.com/
2019-04-25 08:47:57 [root] CRITICAL: url whose status is 200 : http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html
```

Why there is a 200 status for `http://quotes.money.163.com/`?
when you input `http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html` in browser,
no content on server for this url,it will redirect into `http://quotes.money.163.com/` in 5 seconds and the http code for `http://quotes.money.163.com/` is 200,so there are two 200 status lines here.

What confused me is that no such log info as

```
2019-04-25 08:47:57 [root] CRITICAL: url whose status is 404 : http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600024.html
```

in the log file `mylog`.

How to make `if(response.status == 404):logging.critical("url whose status is 404 : " + response.url)` executed in my scrapy1.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have redirect from 404-page to main. So you can set `dont_redirect` and it will show you needed response. Try this:

```
class InfoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
    name = 'info'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.money.163.com']
    start_urls = [
        r"http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html",
        r"http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600024.html"
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'dont_redirect': True})

    def parse(self, response):
        if response.status == 200:
            logging.critical("url whose status is 200 : " + response.url)
        if response.status == 404:
            logging.critical("url whose status is 404 : " + response.url)
```

So, now I get in my log:

```
2019-04-25 08:09:23 [root] CRITICAL: url whose status is 200 : http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600023.html
2019-04-25 08:09:23 [root] CRITICAL: url whose status is 404 : http://quotes.money.163.com/f10/gszl_600024.html
```